# How to update table by of the records in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have a table in PostgerSQL and I need to make N entries in the table twice and for the first half I need to fill in the partner_id field with the value 1 and the second half with the value partner_id = 2.

i try to `

```
update USERS_TABLE set user_rule_id = 1;
update USERS_TABLE set user_rule_id = 2 where USERS_TABLE.id > count(*)/2;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I depends a lot how precise the number of users have to be that are updated with 1 or 2.

The following would be quite unprecise,a s it doesn't take the exact number of user that already exist8after deleting some rows the numbers doesn't fit anymore.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE
```

| id | user_rule_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

If you have a lot of deleted rows and want still the half of the users, you can choose following approach, which does  rely on the id, but at teh actual row number

```
UPDATE USERS_TABLE1
 set user_rule_id = CASE WHEN rn <= (SELECT count(*) FROM USERS_TABLE1)/ 2 then 1
  ELSE 2 END
FROM (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY id) rn FROM USERS_TABLE1) t
WHERE USERS_TABLE1.id = t.id;
```

> ```
> UPDATE 5
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE1
```

| id | user_rule_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MHWAFl09)

In the sample case it it the same result, but when you have a lot of rows and a bunch of the deleted users, the senind will give you quite a good result